# How to make the dynamic link possible

Tags: c, unix, dll

I am using ssh to do some computing in a server. But I am completely new to unix. I have a .so file needs to be linked to the program. However, when I run the program, it reports the following error

```
MatMult.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Link error: 'MatMult' cannot load dll
Link error: 'MatMult' undefined function
```

I think I need to change LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make the .so file on the path. But I have no idea how to write it. The original line is

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$OXHOME/bin64:$niqlowHOME/include:$OXDEV
```

My question is how to modify this line to make the link possible. And is there any resources you would recommend for me to read to understand what does that line do.

Comment: Removed ddl tag; dll might be relevant instead (though it is for Microsoft), or shared-libraries.  There isn't enough information here.  The setting of LD_LIBRARY_PATH has no effect on the compiler linking operations.  You might specify link-time options (`-Wl,rpath=/some/where`, or thereabouts) to identify where the shared library is at run-time, or you might add the directory holding the shared library with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/some/where`, optionally prefixed by `export`.

Comment: I meant dll , instead of ddl

Answer (score 0):

If you are compiling some program which requires linking to the said '.so' file, then you can use:

gcc -L[path of the .so file] -o output -l[library name]

And if you are running a program that requires .so library, simply copy the library file to /usr/lib directory.

Otherwise please elaborate your query. Thanks